# How to extract common elements from nD numpy arrays? Tried but it's not efficient

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, tuples, numpy-ndarray

I have a NumPy array that looks similar to the pythonic list of lists of lists (if I am correct to say lists twice) given as below:

```
tempo= [   array([[ 3,  9],[12, 16],[19, 20]], dtype=int64), 
           array([[ 3,  9],[12, 14],[19, 20]], dtype=int64),
           array([[ 4,  7],[12, 14],[19, 20]], dtype=int64)     ]
```

I want to extract the common elements from this which will be [19,20] here. **I have tried** **as below** based on internet answers.  and also commands like intersect1d/2d, something like below

```
np.array([x for x in set(tuple(x) for x in tempo[0]) & set(tuple(x) for x in tempo[1])& set(tuple(x) for x in tempo[2])])
```

**This works perfectly BUT** the size of the tempo varies and its generation is dependent on something else in my code. So, obviously, I can't use this approach and I want to achieve this with a general piece of code. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Can you not use a for loop to step over the x sub arrays? And inside that loop you would go through each item in the subarray and do the set additions as you're doing.  Then you will have x sets.  Then do your intersection of those sets.

Comment: @I will try this now and update here soon. Actually I have always been a Matlab coder and this is the first time writing a big code in Python. That's why I tend to think maybe there is an elegant solution rather than me going logically from small to big steps. But i will try your method now.

Comment: Yeah, so how would you do this in matlab?  Selecting common elements (which themselves are arrays) from a list of arrays doesn't seem like a common thing to do.  Are there built in functions you can use in matlab to accomplish this?

Comment: The set stuff is implement in C I think, so that should be fast.  But for loops in Python can be quite slow.  And that includes the list comprehensions.

Comment: @davo36 Sorry for the late reply. In Matlab, I had used for loops to traverse and using saying like store a 1 in an array if common element found or else 0. And at the end, I use a condition like any() to see if there are any 1s and so on. It did the purpose but I know this isn't an efficient way. I can code well but I am not really an efficient coder who uses 1-2 line commands to solve stuff! That's why when I am writing the same in Python now I am trying to learn conciseness rather than again using for loops.